# Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

This code shown an error : "Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController". Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

```
@objc static func listBtn()
    {
        drawerVw = DrawerView(aryControllers: DrawerArray.array, isBlurEffect: true, isHeaderInTop: false, controller: UIViewController.self)
        //drawerVw = DrawerView(aryControllers: DrawerArray.array, isBlurEffect: true, isHeaderInTop: false, controller: self)
        drawerVw.delegate = UIViewController.self as? DrawerControllerDelegate
        //drawerVw.delegate = self
        drawerVw.changeUserName(name: "New Delhi")
        drawerVw.show()
    }
```

Comment: You need to pass UIViewController instance as an argument and not its type. Same for setting the delegate.

Comment: Delete `self` from this `UIViewController.self` also You have to pass the UIViewController instance ex: `UIViewController()` also it should be your viewcontroller

Comment: Why you commented `drawerVw = DrawerView(aryControllers: DrawerArray.array, isBlurEffect: true, isHeaderInTop: false, controller: self)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this code. This code is working perfectly on my side.

Class

```
@objc static func listBtn() {
        UIViewController.showListButton(navigationController: navController)
}
```

Extension

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIViewController
{
    static func showListButton(navigationController: UINavigationController)
    {
        if let currentVC = navigationController.visibleViewController
        {
            drawerVw = DrawerView(aryControllers: DrawerArray.array, isBlurEffect: true, isHeaderInTop: false, controller: currentVC)
            drawerVw.delegate = currentVC as? DrawerControllerDelegate
            drawerVw.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI `UIViewController.self` is the class type, not a class object. Rather use weak reference of `self` to pass in function:

```
@objc static func listBtn() {
weak var weakSelf = self
    var drawerVw = DrawerView(aryControllers: DrawerArray.array, isBlurEffect: true, isHeaderInTop: false, controller: weakSelf)
    drawerVw.delegate = self
    drawerVw.changeUserName(name: "New Delhi")
    drawerVw.show()
}
```

**Update:**

If you wish to use it in multiple view controller, then create an `extension of UIViewController`. Like this:

```
extension UIViewController: DrawerControllerDelegate {
    @objc static func listBtn() {
        weak var weakSelf = self
        var drawerVw = DrawerView(aryControllers: DrawerArray.array, isBlurEffect: true, isHeaderInTop: false, controller: weakSelf)
        drawerVw.delegate = self
        drawerVw.changeUserName(name: "New Delhi")
        drawerVw.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i want to use that function in all the view controllers.

Comment: You can create an extension of `UIViewController` for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. link the delegate protocol for accessing the delegate methods.
2. Instead of writing UIViewController.self use as self

Answer (score 0):

If you make a variable like this:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatView") as? HomeViewController
```

it should remove that error.